# RegEx for extracting US address not working when address is separated with newline

Tags: regex

I have the following RegEx to extract US address from a string.

```
(\d+)[ \n]+((\w+[ ,])+[\$\n, ]+){2}([a-zA-Z]){2}[$\n, ]+(\d){5}
```

This is not working when the address is in the below format.

```
2933 Glen Crow Court
San Jose
CA 95148
```

and is working for the below data.

```
2933 Glen Crow Court,
San Jose, CA 95148
```

.

```
2933 Glen Crow Court, San Jose, CA 95148
```

Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Following your original pattern, a possible fix might look like `(\d+)\s+(\w+(?:[$\s,]+\w+)*?)[$,\s]+([a-zA-Z]{2}[$,\s]+\d{5})`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/pIQZ7K/1).

Comment: Just FYI: the issue is that `[ ,])+[\$\n, ]+` part requires at least two consecutive non-word chars (`[ ,]` requires 1 space or comma and `[\$\n, ]+` requires 1 or more `$`, newline, comma or space) and there is only a newline between `Court` and `San`.

Comment: Another regex idea: `(\d+)\s+([\s\S]*?)\s+([a-zA-Z]{2}[$\n, ]+\d{5})\b` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/pIQZ7K/2))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simplify your pattern to something like this for matching the address, whether in one line or in multiple line.

```
\b\d+(?:\s+[\w,]+)+?\s+[a-zA-Z]{2}\s+\d{5}\b
```

**Regex Explanation:**

- `\b\d+` - Starts matching with word boundary with one or more digit
- `(?:\s+[\w,]+)+?` - A non-grouping pattern that matches one or more whitespace then text having one or more word character and comma and whole of it one or more times but in non-greedy way.
- `\s+[a-zA-Z]{2}` - Matches one or more whitespace then two alphabetic characters to expect text like `CA`, `NY`
- `\s+\d{5}\b` - Followed by one or more whitespace then finally five digits with word boundary to avoid matching partially in a larger text

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wE5jb1/5)**

Answer (score 1):

Add `?` to the `[ ,]` check:

```
(\d+)[ \n]+((\w+[ ,]?)+[\$\n, ]+){2}([a-zA-Z]){2}[$\n, ]+(\d){5}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this pattern `\d+\s+[\w ]+[\s,]+[\w ]+[\s,]+\w+ \d+`

Explanation:

`\d+\s+` - match one ore more digits then match one ore more white spaces

`[\w ]+[\s,]+` - match one or more word characters or space, then one or more white spaces or comma

`\w+ \d+` -match one ore more word charaters, space and onre or more digits

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZQkxWg/3)

Answer (score 0):

Not drake but you can thank me later...

```
r"(?:(\d+ [A-Za-z][A-Za-z ]+)[\s,]*([A-Za-z#0-9][A-Za-z#0-9 ]+)?[\s,]*)?(?:([A-Za-z][A-Za-z ]+)[\s,]+)?((?=AL|AK|AS|AZ|AR|CA|CO|CT|DE|DC|FM|FL|GA|GU|HI|ID|IL|IN|IA|KS|KY|LA‌​|ME|MH|MD|MA|MI|MN|MS|MO|MT|NE|NV|NH|NJ|NM|NY|NC|ND|MP|OH|OK|OR|PW|PA|PR|RI|SC|SD‌​|TN|TX|UT|VT|VI|VA|WA|WV|WI|WY)[A-Z]{2})(?:[,\s]+(\d{5}(?:-\d{4})?))?"
```

you can test it out here... [demo](https://regexr.com/6qduj)

**note:** this only works for us addresses